# how to render all the tab content at once on safari browser?

Tags: javascript, extjs, safari, fusioncharts

I have a tabpanel in ExtJS with multiple tabs containing FusionCharts.
     I want to render all the tabs at one time and not when user clicks each tab.
     This only fails to render all tabs in Safari.

```
    code:
    Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    id: 'tbPnl',
    deferredRender: false,
    layout: 'card',
    layoutOnTabChange: true,
    defaults:{
    hideMode: 'offsets', 
    },

    renderTo: 'reportDiv',
    //autoScroll: true,
    width: 1400,
    flex: 1,
    //height: '100%',
    height: 1200
    //margin: 20,


    });
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:perl]?

Comment: Are you using JS or Flash variant of charts? At which point in code are you rendering the charts? Can you post a more elaborate code?

Comment: i am using Flash variant of charts. i am exporting all the result in PDF